# is it possible to build android for any device that passes the minimum requirements?

Tags: c#, c++, android, c

Suppose i have a device that passes the minimum requirements for android OS , now can i program the bootloader and all and run android OS in  it?

the device is : LG gt350i

i wouldnt want to run android 3.0 , perhaps 1.6 or 2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the code is open source, you can port it to anything you want, if you have the development tools for your device and can write drivers for it's peripherals. Unfortunately companies usually don't provide that tools for users (you can develop an app for their OS, but you can't change the OS itself), nor hardware spec that would allow you to do so.

Comment: thnx.....i think i will somehow have to get the devel tools and port the code....(long process) :D